# How to compare two rfs directories with `diff`?

Tags: linux, directory, comparison, diff, symlink

I have two rfs dirctories I would like to compare to each other with `diff`. Both directories represent a rfs of some other system, and may contain links. If those links are absolute, they will point to something useless.

For example, I have one rfs with the following symlink (inside the rfs):

```
/usr/test -> /home/test/file1
```

Now I have this complete rfs inside a directory named `/home/user/compare`, and the absolute paths of both files mentioned above are

```
/home/user/compare/usr/test
/home/user/compare/home/test/file1
```

Clearly, the symlink `/home/user/compare/usr/test` does not point to the right file. And because of that a comparison with the files in `/home/usr/compare` with some other rfs directory will fail for those symlinks.

Is it possible to setup `diff` so it assumes not `/` as root but `/home/user/compare` as root (for the comparison), so that the given absolute symlink points to something valid, and `diff` takes it into account?

Maybe there is a similar Linux command I can use for that?

Comment: I know "find" has been useful to do these sorts of things, but I am not quite sure how to make it work for this situation.  Hopefully it is a start at least.